# A2lix TranslationFormBundle - Gedmo Doctrine Extension - Unwanted form fields

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, internationalization, translation

I am trying to build forms for translatable entities but i get 4 form fields that i don't want.

It seems these fields are coming from the [Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractTranslation](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity/MappedSuperclass/AbstractTranslation.php) but i wonder what i need to do with these fields ?

Is it normal that they are appearing in the translation form ?

[image]

If someone have usefull examples that would be great.

- It's a Symfony2 project.
- Doctrine extensions are installed with stof:
  https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/
- Aj2lix TranslationFormBundle:
  https://github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle

Please find below the following files:

- Page.php (this is the main entity)
- PageTranslation.php (the translation entity)

**Page.php**

```
<?php

namespace Syms\PageBundle\Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Page
 *
 * @Gedmo\Tree(type="nested")
 * @ORM\Table(name="syms_page")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Syms\PageBundle\Entity\PageRepository")
 */
class Page
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean", nullable=false, options={"default":0})
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_homepage", type="boolean", nullable=false, options={"default":0})
     */
    private $isHomepage;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    protected $translations;


    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeLeft
     * @ORM\Column(name="lft", type="integer")
     */
    private $lft;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeRight
     * @ORM\Column(name="rgt", type="integer")
     */
    private $rgt;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeLevel
     * @ORM\Column(name="lvl", type="integer")
     */
    private $lvl;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeParent
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeRoot
     * @ORM\Column(name="root", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $root;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Page", mappedBy="parent")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"lft" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * Required for Translatable behaviour
     * @Gedmo\Locale
     */
    protected $locale;


    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->translations = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * Set isHomepage
     *
     * @param boolean $isHomepage
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setIsHomepage($isHomepage)
    {
        $this->isHomepage = $isHomepage;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isHomepage
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getIsHomepage()
    {
        return $this->isHomepage;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }


    public function setParent(Page $parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * Set lft
     *
     * @param integer $lft
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setLft($lft)
    {
        $this->lft = $lft;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lft
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getLft()
    {
        return $this->lft;
    }

    /**
     * Set rgt
     *
     * @param integer $rgt
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setRgt($rgt)
    {
        $this->rgt = $rgt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get rgt
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getRgt()
    {
        return $this->rgt;
    }

    /**
     * Set lvl
     *
     * @param integer $lvl
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setLvl($lvl)
    {
        $this->lvl = $lvl;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lvl
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getLvl()
    {
        return $this->lvl;
    }

    /**
     * Set root
     *
     * @param integer $root
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setRoot($root)
    {
        $this->root = $root;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get root
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getRoot()
    {
        return $this->root;
    }


    /**
     * Add children
     *
     * @param \Syms\PageBundle\Entity\Page $children
     * @return Page
     */
    public function addChild(Page $children)
    {
        $this->children[] = $children;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove children
     *
     * @param \Syms\PageBundle\Entity\Page $children
     */
    public function removeChild(Page $children)
    {
        $this->children->removeElement($children);
    }

    /**
     * Get children
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }



    public function getTranslations()
    {
        return $this->translations;
    }

    public function addTranslation(PageTranslation $t)
    {
        $this->translations->add($t);
        $t->setObject($this);
    }

    public function removeTranslation(PageTranslation $t)
    {
        $this->translations->removeElement($t);
    }

    public function setTranslations($translations)
    {
        $this->translations = $translations;
    }

    public function setTranslatableLocale($locale)
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;
    }
}
```

**PageTranslation.php**

```
<?php

namespace Syms\PageBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractTranslation;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
* @ORM\Table(name="ext_translations_page", indexes={
*      @ORM\Index(name="page_translation_idx", columns={"locale", "object_class", "field", "foreign_key"})
* })
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\Repository\TranslationRepository")
*/
class PageTranslation extends AbstractTranslation
{

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(name="meta_title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $metaTitle;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(name="meta_keywords", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $metaKeywords;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(name="meta_description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $metaDescription;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(name="url_key", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $urlKey;


    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return PageTranslation
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set metaTitle
     *
     * @param string $metaTitle
     * @return PageTranslation
     */
    public function setMetaTitle($metaTitle)
    {
        $this->metaTitle = $metaTitle;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get metaTitle
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getMetaTitle()
    {
        return $this->metaTitle;
    }

    /**
     * Set metaKeywords
     *
     * @param string $metaKeywords
     * @return PageTranslation
     */
    public function setMetaKeywords($metaKeywords)
    {
        $this->metaKeywords = $metaKeywords;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get metaKeywords
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getMetaKeywords()
    {
        return $this->metaKeywords;
    }

    /**
     * Set metaDescription
     *
     * @param string $metaDescription
     * @return PageTranslation
     */
    public function setMetaDescription($metaDescription)
    {
        $this->metaDescription = $metaDescription;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get metaDescription
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getMetaDescription()
    {
        return $this->metaDescription;
    }

    /**
     * Set urlKey
     *
     * @param string $urlKey
     * @return PageTranslation
     */
    public function setUrlKey($urlKey)
    {
        $this->urlKey = $urlKey;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get urlKey
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUrlKey()
    {
        return $this->urlKey;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm having the exact same problem. Did you find a solution for this problem? It might be helpful if you could post the code of your PageType.

Comment: Hi, sorry i got too frustrated by this and abandoned :'(

Answer (score 1):

I've finally succeeded in displaying the correct fields.

You have to downgrade the a2lix form bundle to version 1.4.

In fact, in version 2.0, the field type "a2lix_translations_gedmo" is no more available, which is actually what you need when using Gedmo Translatable.

There's nothing to change on your entity side. Just follow the [doc](http://a2lix.fr/bundles/translation-form/1.4.html) for the config.yml, and use "a2lix_translations_gedmo" in your PageType :

```
$builder->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations_gedmo', array(
    'translatable_class' => "Syms\PageBundle\Entity\Page"
);
```

I've also red somewhere that you can keep using version 2.0 of a2lix Form Bundle, but in this case you have to use a specific [branch](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/tree/wip-v2.4.0) of doctrine extensions (wip-v2.4.0).

Regards,